# Getting following error while executing CronJobSchedulingExample

Tags: java, ignite

Getting following error while running CronJobSchedulingExample example from github https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java-lgpl/org/apache/ignite/examples/misc/schedule/ComputeScheduleExample.java

```
  Exception in thread "main" class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Current Ignite configuration does not support schedule functionality (consider adding ignite-schedule module to classpath).
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.schedule.IgniteNoopScheduleProcessor.processorException(IgniteNoopScheduleProcessor.java:50)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.schedule.IgniteNoopScheduleProcessor.schedule(IgniteNoopScheduleProcessor.java:43)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteSchedulerImpl.scheduleLocal(IgniteSchedulerImpl.java:123)
        at com.mstorm.ignition.CronJobSchedulingExample.main(CronJobSchedulingExample.java:38)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `ignite-schedule` module in project classpath. Check if it's added in your pom.xml or, if you're running it using `ignite.sh`, - copy `ignite-schedule` directory from `libs/optional` to `libs`.

Comment: I have added Ignite -schedule module in pom with version 1.0.0 but still getting this error

Comment: If the class is in the classpath, you should not be getting this error. Please clean out your Maven repository and try again.